# How to unit test main() in VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, program-entry-point, googletest

Is there a simple way to unit test `main()` in Visual Studio 2019 in C++?

I've tried `#including` a main.h and calling `main()` from the test, but it 'looks' like the test's `main()` is getting called instead, causing a recursion.

I would like to introduce testing to students very early (write code to make tests green) and the students will have no experience(yet) of functions or classes.

FYI we're using GoogleTest, but that choice can be changed.

Comment: You can only have one entry point, and I think (not 100% sure though) all standalone C++ test runners require their own entry point (or require it being called from main()) so not much choice there. Seems better to first explain students to explain what a function is, then test it. Also because in any real environment main() will do way more than can be tested in a single unit test, and will be split in functions anyway?

Comment: You could do it the ways SDL2 wraps MSVC's main function, by defining a `main` macro which renames it to something else. That comes with its own can of worms though.

Comment: I don't think it'll be too much of a stretch to write a `myProgram()` function that is called directly from `main`. Sure, your students don't yet know functions, but if your test would call `main`, it might as well call `myProgram` (and so might `main`). It's just some more scaffolding and will be recognized by students as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main` is special, because you can have only one `main` in the program. Also `main` isnt something you typically unit test. However, the solution is rather straightforward

```
// the "main" function you can test
int my_main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // ...
}

// your main (the one you dont include for testing
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return my_main(argc,argv);
}
```

> and the students will have no experience(yet) of functions or classes

I have doubts on this strategy. Composability is a precondition for unit-testing. Unit testing makes sense if you have small units that can be tested in isolation. Before being able to unit test `main` one needs a basic understanding that there are functions that can be called (and tested).

Answer (score 0):

I would advice against this strategy.

New programmers don't start with testing. Before one can even think about testing they need to be introduced to at least functions.

While it is technically possible to test main, I would stop to think think what message this is sending. If this has a chance to create bad habits, then it would not be worth doing in the first place.

Just to be clear, I am not suggesting students to go away for 2 years until they are experts and only then think of testing. No, I am simply suggesting they should at least know the basics and be familiar with functions before being introduced to testing.

An important step, for sure is to get to the point where one can write testable code, you don't get to that stage without actually trying to test code, then you see where the issues are, so from this point of view, testing should be introduced early in the development process

Comment: "Once the basics are mastered .." try to explain this to a TDD evangelist :P

Comment: I am not a TDD evangelist, but I do think testing should be at the very beginning, not only after you mastered the basics (if that would be the case I would never reach a point where I can write a test in c++). The first code one writes should be a test. Seems like your opinion differs...

Comment: having a different opinion is totally fine with me :)